# Get unique list of values from a dynamic list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of dynamic objects that are returned from the database like this:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> list = _repository.All(whereClause);
```

What I then need to do with that list is get a list of unique values for each column name that is specified in an array. So something like this:

```
List<string> columns = new string[] {"Col1","Col1"};

foreach(string column in columns)
{ 
    //get unique value for column and add them to some collection 
    list.Select().Where(???)
}
```

Because the list is dynamic I am not sure how to select based on the column names.

Can anyone help please

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2783502/181108

Comment: How the columns are distinguished in your dynamic element? What `_repository.All()` is actually returning?

Answer (score 2):

What about using a helper class to dynamically access the properties by name (could be extended to use some caching):

```
public class ObjectUtils
{
    public static object GetPropertyByName(object obj, string name)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        PropertyInfo propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
        if (propInfo == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        object value = propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then get the data like this:

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new { Col1 = "AB", Col2 = 23 });
list.Add(new { Col1 = "CD", Col2 = 23 });
list.Add(new { Col1 = "AB", Col2 = 5 });
list.Add(new { Col1 = "EF", Col2 = 9 });

string[] columns = new string[] { "Col1", "Col2" };
foreach (string column in columns)
{
    var elems = list.Select(d => ObjectUtils.GetPropertyByName(d, column)).Distinct().ToList();
    // elems will be "AB", "CD", "EF" for Col1
    //           and 23, 5, 9 for Col2
}
```

If it doesn't compile, make sure to add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp

Answer (score 1):

Without more info I would try something like this:

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new { a = "Col1", b = "b" });
list.Add(new { a = "Col2", b = "c" });
list.Add(new { a = "Col1", b = "c" });

string[] columns = new string[] { "Col1", "Col2" };

foreach (string column in columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(column);
    //get unique value for column and add them to some collection 
    var select=list.Where((x) => { return x.a == column; }).Select(x=>x.b);
    select.ToList().ForEach((x) => { Console.WriteLine("{0}",x ); });
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: The compiler throws error first on your select=list.where statement as Where doesnt exist

Answer (score -1):

Can:

```
foreach(string column in columns)
{ 
    list.Where(x => x == column);
    list.Distinct();
}
```

Help you?

But then you can skip the foreach loop:

```
list = list.Where(x => colums.Contains(x));
```

and have you duplets:

```
list = list.Distinct();
```

Comment: Something like that would help but first I would need to select all the values for a column into a list, the column is a string variable (from the array)