# How can I target an object's property with a string?

Tags: c#, object, reflection, properties

How can I refer to the properties of an object of type Employee, for example, dynamically? I'm after something like `employee."hasBeenPaid"`? Does it involve reflection?

```
class Employee
{
    String name;
    Bool hasBeenPaid;
}
```

Comment: What's the broader goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @CodeCaster It is a duplicate if you assume the answer is going to be reflection, but there are other ways to do it that the linked answers don't cover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
Type type = your_class.GetType();
PropertyInfo propinfo = type.GetProperty("hasBeenPaid");
```

If you need the value

```
value = propinfo.GetValue(your_class, null);
```

Comment: And then propInfo.GetValue(your_object, null). Also Type.GetProperty has several arguments (BindingFlags at least) which allows you to get public or not public properties, static or non-static (instance), etc.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyF, you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [dynamic C# feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx); and yes, it will use reflection at runtime to resolve your properties.

Comment: Technically this won't work, the DLR will throw a runtime error about the accessibility of the properties (which are default private) and you cannot access this as "strings", but as coded duck-typed property names.

Comment: @Adam: the OP did not specify she need to retrieve the properties using strings and I think the C# dynamic feature could cover what she is looking for.

Comment: The Question title specifically says "with a string" and the sample usage shows a string. Use of `dynamic` in it's basic form isn't enough to cover these requirements, use of a string also implies the ability to provide a variable instead of a literla. `dynamic` without any changes uses duck-typing, if you want to use strings you need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783502/c-sharp-using-the-dynamic-keyword-to-access-properties-via-strings-without-refle And it doesn't work against his provided entity and assumes public member access.

Comment: You are right, @Adam, and thanks for sharing this cool link.

Comment: @DeeMac It is just a placeholder, there are no clues available as to your gender other than your last comment. Don't take it personally.